# Pipeline fill-mask error with custom Roberta tokenizer

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I’m using [boilerplate code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb#scrollTo=4keFBUjQFOD1) to train a Roberta model on my text corpus.

Everything seems to be going okay until I try to load the pretrained tokenizer into the pipeline. I think it’s looking for a config.json file in the tokenizer folder but the BPE tokenizer is only outputting vocab.json and merges.txt files. what am I missing here?

[link to notebook gist](https://gist.github.com/enpassanty/4bac3d1ed5d8995ac3c48050b0c2aca1)

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful to someone else so I'll keep the post up.  The tokenizer needs to be re-saved as a Roberta tokenizer (not BPE) for fill-mask pipline to work.  [this solution is given here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/12319).  Adding the suggested code lines fixed it:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(tokenizer_folder, return_special_tokens_mask=True, max_length=512)  

tokenizer.save_pretrained(tokenizer_folder)
```